# woo-commerce rest api python pass route as avariable

Tags: python, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

how to pass route as a variable in wcapi call

```
item = '4839'
items = '"' + 'products/' + item + '"'
r = wcapi.put(items, data)
print(r.json())
```

trying using above code i got error massage
{'code': 'rest_no_route', 'message': 'No route was found matching the URL and request method.', 'data': {'status': 404}}

try to send api put call and expecting json success response

Comment: Did you try it on Postman? Did it work?

Comment: im using python its working if i pass it as normal parmarter like wcapi.put("products/4839", data).json()

Comment: Will it work with this? items = 'products/' + item